# Can we use “had” in present tense

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

I’ve got confused by this sentence from “A Study in Scarlet” by Arthur Conan Doyle:

“You had better clean it and load it. He will be a desperate man, and though I
shall take him unawares, it is as well to be ready for anything.”

Answer (score 6):

*You had better* [do something] is a special usage meaning 'you should do it' or 'it would be a good idea to do it'. See [this explanation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/had-better).

Comment: Probably worth mentioning here in the comments that nowadays the *had* is often left out: "You better finish your homework before Mum gets home"